# How can I get the (x,y) values of the line that is plotted by a contour plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis

Is there an easy way to get the (x,y) values of a contour line that was plotted like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [1,2,3,4]
m = [[15,14,13,12],[14,12,10,8],[13,10,7,4],[12,8,4,0]]
cs = plt.contour(x,y,m, [9.5])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Look at the collections property of the returned ContourSet.  In particular the get_paths() method of the first collection returns paired points making up each line segment.

```
cs.collections[0].get_paths()
```

To get a NumPy array of the coordinates, use the `Path.vertices` attribute.

```
p1 = cs.collections[0].get_paths()[0]  # grab the 1st path
coor_p1 = p1.vertices
```

Comment: This is really useful, thanks! Do you know of any way of obtaining/interpolating equally spaced points on the contour curve? (the points returned in this way are not equally spaced)

Answer (score 2):

Going through the collections and extracting the paths and vertices is not the most straight forward or fastest thing to do. The returned Contour object actually has attributes for the segments via `cs.allsegs`, which returns a nested list of shape [level][element][vertex_coord]:

```
num_levels = len(cs.allsegs)
num_element = len(cs.allsegs[0])  # in level 0
num_vertices = len(cs.allsegs[0][0])  # of element 0, in level 0
num_coord = len(cs.allsegs[0][0][0])  # of vertex 0, in element 0, in level 0
```

Hence the vertices of an all paths can be extracted as:

```
cs.allsegs[i][j]  # for element j, in level i
```

See reference:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/contour_api.html

Comment: Nice answer. However, the number of vertices included in `cs.allsegs` is not the same as the number of vertices included in the path collection in the solution proposed by Mark. It is consistently larger, and I wonder why. Just compare: (1) Using `cs.collections`: `list(zip(cs.levels, [np.sum([len(path.vertices) for path in cs.collections[level].get_paths()]) for level in range(len(cs.levels))]))` WITH (2) Using `cs.allsegs`: `list(zip(cs.levels, [np.sum([len(segment) for segment in contour_level]) for contour_level in cs.allsegs]))`.