# Extract specific paths from matplotlib contour plot

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following contour plots:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,6, figsize=(18,3))

for idx in range(6):
    axes[idx].contour(KX[kxl:kxr,kxl:kxr],KY[kxl:kxr,kxl:kxr],eigs[kxl:kxr,kxl:kxr,idx].real, levels=[0])
    axes[idx].set_xlabel(x_label_k)

axes[0].set_ylabel(y_label_k)
```

[image: 6 eigenvalue contours]

Overlapping them results in the following image:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(4,4))

for idx in range(6):
    ax.contour(KX[kxl:kxr,kxl:kxr],KY[kxl:kxr,kxl:kxr],eigs[kxl:kxr,kxl:kxr,idx].real, levels=[0])

ax.set_xlabel(x_label_k)
ax.set_ylabel(y_label_k)
```

[image: overlapped contours]

From the above image, I am interested in plotting just the 4 "circle-like" shapes that are shown in the edited image below:

[image: edited circles]

If possible, I would like the pairs of (kx, ky) points that make up these elongated circles, without any of the points from the other artifacts.

I have seen that there is a way of extracting point values from a contour plot along the lines of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666056/matplotlib-extracting-data-from-contour-lines), however, that gives me a set of (2000,2000) points which I have no idea how to filter. I was thinking maybe something can be done based on paths from the contour plots?

Note that one can actually see where the circle-shapes originate in the row of 6 plots, but the problem is that in order to make up the 2 smaller inner circles one has to combine subplots 2,3,4 and 5. For the larger outer ones, it is simpler as they are relative well separated in subplots 5 and 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you have set of **points** extracted from contours, try [RANSAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC). An implementation in `C#` to extract circles from noisy points is given [here](http://accord.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Sources/Accord.MachineLearning/Geometry/RansacCircle.cs). A general and simple `Python` implementation is given [here](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/RANSAC).

You may also try `Least Square Circle Fitting` for which an example in `Python` is given [here](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Least_Squares_Circle).

Good Luck.