# Matplotlib evenly spaced contour lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm learning how to use the contour function and I was assigned the task of plotting 25 evenly spaced lines using a 4th parameter.

Edit:
This is the desired image:
[image]

```
z = np.load('heights.npy')
plt.contour(np.transpose(z), 25) #Now plotting with 25 evenly spaced contours
plt.title('even contour lines')
plt.savefig('myFig2.png', format='png')
```

[image]

I've checked [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) and I can't find what I need. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

I've also looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666056/matplotlib-extracting-data-from-contour-lines) but as you can see, my lines are not evenly spaced.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "evenly spaced" means "with respect to level value". Unless your function is linear, these equilevel curves (dunno what the proper name is) will never be actually evenly spaced in the `(x,y)` plane. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: In the sample image I am to produce, the lines are evenly spaced

Comment: Have you also checked `help(plt.contour)`? It says `contour(X,Y,Z,V) - draw contour lines at the values specified in sequence *V*`. Have you tried providing an equidistant list `V`?

Comment: In [21]: np.shape(z)
Out[21]:  (101L, 76L)

Comment: Adding (101, 76) just gives me more errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91941/discussion-between-brian-b-and-andras-deak).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to manually specify the levels for your plot, otherwise `matplotlib` will determine the levels for you, which is clearly not what you want.

```
z = np.load('heights.npy')
plt.contour(np.transpose(z),np.linspace(z.min(),z.max(),25)) 
plt.title('even contour lines')
plt.savefig('myFig2.png', format='png')
```

This will set the `contour` levels such that it divides the span of your `z` data to 24 equidistant intervals, giving 25 lines.