# ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib._cntr'

Tags: matplotlib

When I run

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I get following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/wayne/alphaWorldsPython/code/mapTest.py", line 12, in <module>
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "/home/wayne/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
File "/home/wayne/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 36, in <module>
    import matplotlib.contour as contour
File "/home/wayne/matplotlib/contour.py", line 14, in <module>
    import matplotlib._cntr as _cntr
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib._cntr'
```

When I look in matplotlib indeed ._cntr is not present.
I have tried reinstalling and updating.  No change.

Comment: I think you will need to add a lot more information before anybody can help you with this. What operating system are you on, how did you install matplotlib, what version of python and matplotlib are you using, ... ?

Comment: Such errors usually occur when using a wrong matplotlib version, which does not match with the version of numpy or python. E.g. if you have a 32 bit python, but install the 64 bit matplotlib binaries or vice versa.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 15.04, Python 3.4, Numpy 1.9.2.  I first installed with conda, then cloning from gethub, and finally sudo apt-get install matplotlib.  Got the same errors with each.  I understand both matplotlib and python 3.4 are 64 bit.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using matplotlib 2.1.1.

Comment: I fixed the problem, but have another.  I removed the matplotlib and recloned it from git hub.  

    git clone git://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git
 
The new error is ImportError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python
    import matplotlib 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.cm
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

Answer (score 1):

._cntr was a private module and it was removed from matplotlib. you can install this to still have the ._cntr in your matplotlib 
https://github.com/matplotlib/legacycontour