# How to find and draw the intersection points of contour shapes

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, contour

I'm trying to find the points of intersection between the line passing through point V and conic. The conic graph is not solvable relative to y ( or x), so it was depicted using contour. Is there a method for finding the intersection points of contour graphs? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JcoI.png)

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p = (input("choose point P on axis OX: "))
print(p)
q = (input("choose point Q on axis OX: "))
print(q)
v = (input("choose point V on axis OX: "))
print(v)

k=3
X = np.arange(-50, 50, 0.05)
Y = k*X
plt.plot(X,Y)

plt.plot(0,0)
plt.scatter(0.0, 0.0, color='white', marker='o')
plt.text(0.0, 0.0, "O", horizontalalignment="center")

plt.plot(-v,0)
plt.scatter(-v, 0, color='red', marker='o')
plt.text(-v, 0.8, "V", horizontalalignment="center")

xmin= -10
xmax= 10
ymin= -10
ymax= 10
ax = plt.gca()
ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
ax.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

#Create random point B1
b1=4
plt.plot(0.0,b1)
plt.scatter(0.0, b1, color='blue', marker='o')
plt.text(0.8, b1, "B1", horizontalalignment="center")

x, y = np.meshgrid(X, X)

#Create VB1
l3 = b1*x+b1*v - v*y
vb = plt.contour(x,y, l3, [0], colors='k')
# l3 = b1*X/v + b1
# plt.plot(X,l3)

#Create conic
conic = x*x*b1*2*p*k-x*x*b1*2*q*k+x*x*k*k+y*y-b1*2*y+2*b1*q*x*y
cnc = plt.contour(x, y, (conic), [0], colors='k')
```

I tried to do something like that:

```
  c = cnc.intersection(vb)
  print(c)
```

or

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766692/intersection-of-two-graphs-in-python-find-the-x-value
    idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(cnc - vb))).flatten()
    plt.plot(x[idx], y[idx], 'ro')
```

My last attempt:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
p,q,v,k,b=5,7,2,3,4
X = np.arange(-50, 50, 0.05)

plt.plot(-v,0)
plt.scatter(-v, 0, color='red', marker='o')
plt.text(-v, 0.8, "V", horizontalalignment="center")
xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax=-10,10,-10,10
ax = plt.gca()
ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
ax.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

plt.plot(0.0,b)
plt.scatter(0.0, 1, color='blue', marker='o')
x, y = np.meshgrid(X, X)

l = b*x+b*v-v*y
vb = plt.contour(x,y, l, [0], colors='k')

conic = x*x*b*2*p*k-x*x*b*2*q*k+x*x*k*k+y*y-b*2*y+2*b*q*x*y
cnc = plt.contour(x, y, (conic), [0], colors='k')

c = cnc.collections[0].get_paths()[1]
v = c.vertices
x1 = v[:,0]
y1 = v[:,1]
plt.plot(x1,y1)

vb1 = vb.collections[0].get_paths()[0]
v1 = vb1.vertices
x2 = v1[:,0]
y2 = v1[:,1]
plt.plot(x2,y2,color='red')

# def find_roots(x,y):
#      s = np.abs(np.diff(np.sign(y))).astype(bool)
#      return x[:-1][s] + np.diff(x)[s]/(np.abs(y[1:][s]/y[:-1][s])+1)
#
# z = find_roots(x1-x2,y1-y2)
# plt.plot(z, np.zeros(len(z)), marker="o", ls="", ms=4)
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu7Gn.png)

Comment: You probably know this, but `print()` prints to stdout. Just saying...

Comment: i used print(c) to check what the operation intersection outputs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909373/how-to-get-values-from-a-graph/46911822#46911822

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  I tried to implement your method . Look like this: `code`m= conic-l3 z = find_roots(x,m)
plt.plot(z, np.zeros(len(z)), marker="o", ls="", ms=4) `code` But the formula of a conic is an implicit function.

Comment: I guess you would want to [extract data from contour lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666056/matplotlib-extracting-data-from-contour-lines) first.

Comment: I tried and got the following this: `code` c = cnc.collections[0].get_paths()[0]
v = c.vertices
x1 = v[:,0]
y1 = v[:,1]
print(x1)
print(y1)
plt.plot(x1,y1,color='red') `code`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I also did the same for the line passing through point V , got the following : `vb1 = vb.collections[0].get_paths()[0]
v1 = vb1.vertices
x2 = v1[:,0]
y2 = v1[:,1]
print(x2)
print(y2)
plt.plot(x2,y2,color='green')` But I do not understand how you can determine the intersection point of these figures.  I tried this: `s=y2-y1` , and got the error: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2999,) (2381,).

Comment: Here's my last try; `import numpy as np`
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
`p,q,v,k,b=5,7,2,3,4`
`X = np.arange(-50, 50, 0.05)`
`plt.plot(-v,0)`
`plt.scatter(-v, 0, color='red', marker='o')`
`plt.plot(0.0,b)`
`plt.scatter(0.0, 1, color='blue', marker='o')`
`x, y = np.meshgrid(X, X)`
`l = b*x+b*v-v*y`
`vb = plt.contour(x,y, l, [0], colors='k')`
`conic = x*x*b*2*p*k-x*x*b*2*q*k+x*x*k*k+y*y-b*2*y+2*b*q*x*y`
`cnc = plt.contour(x, y, (conic), [0], colors='k')`
`c = cnc.collections[0].get_paths()[1]`
`v = c.vertices`
`x1 = v[:,0]`
`y1 = v[:,1]`
`plt.plot(x1,y1)`
`plt.show()`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Of course I did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little more complicated. The problem is that (a) the points in the contour are not necessarily sorted and (b) the two contours do not have a common support.

So one would need to (a) sort the points along x, and (b) create an array of common values, on which to interpolate first.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p,q,v,k,b=5,7,2,3,4
X = np.arange(-50, 50, 0.05)

plt.plot(-v,0)
plt.scatter(-v, 0, color='red', marker='o')
plt.text(-v, 0.8, "V", horizontalalignment="center")
xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax=-10,10,-10,10
ax = plt.gca()
ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
ax.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)


x, y = np.meshgrid(X, X)

l = b*x+b*v-v*y
vb = plt.contour(x,y, l, [0], colors='red')

conic = x*x*b*2*p*k-x*x*b*2*q*k+x*x*k*k+y*y-b*2*y+2*b*q*x*y
cnc = plt.contour(x, y, (conic), [0], colors='blue')

c = cnc.collections[0].get_paths()[1]
v = c.vertices
x1 = np.sort(v[:,0])
y1 = v[np.argsort(v[:,0]),1]

vb1 = vb.collections[0].get_paths()[0]
v1 = vb1.vertices
x2 = np.sort(v1[:,0])
y2 = v1[np.argsort(v1[:,0]),1]


def find_roots(x,y):
    s = np.abs(np.diff(np.sign(y))).astype(bool)
    return x[:-1][s] + np.diff(x)[s]/(np.abs(y[1:][s]/y[:-1][s])+1)

x = np.linspace(max(x1.min(), x2.min()), min(x1.max(), x2.max()), 1000)

y1i = np.interp(x, x1, y1 )  # blue
y2i = np.interp(x, x2, y2 )  # red


x_intersect = find_roots(x,y2i-y1i)
y_intersect = np.interp(x_intersect, x, y2i)

plt.plot(x_intersect, y_intersect, marker="X", ms=5, color="limegreen")
plt.show()
```

The point of intersection is the green dot.

[image]

Of course one needs to do the same for the other arm of the conic contour (`cnc.collections[0].get_paths()[0]`) if desired.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do a further construction of a contour  for the other arm of the conic contour.

Comment: I wanted to clarify: in the case where q is float (`p,q,v,k,b=5,0.7,2,3,4`) an error occurs:
`c = cnc.collections[0].get_paths()[1]`
`IndexError: list index out of range`   How can this be corrected?

Comment: Yes you would need to check how many paths you have and only try to do this for existing paths

Comment: I tried to change it to `c = cnc.collections[0].get_paths()[-1]` . And it worked.