# getting back z value from contourf with x,y coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

this question is related to " [How can I get the (x,y) values of the line that is ploted by a contour plot (matplotlib)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560424/how-can-i-get-the-x-y-values-of-the-line-that-is-ploted-by-a-contour-plot-mat) " and so I use the same kind of example for my question. given:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [1,2,3,4]
z = [[15,14,13,12],[14,12,10,8],[13,10,7,4],[12,8,4,0]]
cs = plt.contourf(x,y,z, [float(i)/10 for i in range(160)])
plt.show()
```

I would like to find a function that give me the z value for a given x and y.
I was imagining something like this exist:

```
>>> cs.get_value(1.5, 1.5)
14.something
```

but I am not able to find an easy way to do it.

Comment: You are asking for interpolation of the discrete data set. This has nothing to do with plotting.

Comment: yes! thanks. found the solution with scipy.interpolate.interp2d. sorry for the stupid question...

Comment: There are hardly any stupid questions -- sometimes it's only a matter of finding the right terms for searching.