# Retrieve matplotlib ContourSet for SymPy plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, sympy

Using SymPy, I can create a contour plot manually using the following code (<s>there isn't yet a built-in contour plotting function</s> **Update**: [SymPy now has a contour plotting function](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/14896)):

```
from sympy import init_session
init_session()
from sympy.plotting.plot import Plot, ContourSeries

# show plot centered at 0,0
x_min = -7
x_max = 7
y_min = -5
y_max = 5

# contour plot of inverted cone
my_plot = Plot(
    ContourSeries(
        sqrt(x**2 + y**2),
        (x,x_min,x_max),
        (y,y_min,y_max)
    )
)
my_plot.show()
```

[image: contour plot 14x10]

Currently, when SymPy calls `contour()`, [it does not appear to be saving the returned ContourSet](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/35e8c28de549f6f898ef5b09f8e39ca9a6a6196c/sympy/plotting/plot.py#L911) (**Update:** I have [filed a issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12100) to see if the ContourSet can be saved):

```
class MatplotlibBackend(BaseBackend):
    ...
    def process_series(self):  
        ... 
        for s in self.parent._series:
            # Create the collections
            ...
            elif s.is_contour:
                self.ax.contour(*s.get_meshes()) # returned ContourSet not saved by SymPy
```

In other examples where modifications are performed to the plot, such as [adding inline labels using `clabel()`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html), the ContourSet (`CS`) is needed:

```
# Create a simple contour plot with labels using default colors.
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z) # CS is the ContourSet
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.title('Simplest default with labels')
```

[image: contour plot with labels]

Going back to the SymPy example, `my_plot._backend` does provide access to the figure and axes; what workarounds are possible to keep or obtain access to the ContourSet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option when SymPy's built-in plotting capabilities fall short of what you want is to use matplotlib directly. The key is to use `lambdify` to convert the SymPy expression to a NumPy function.

```
f = lambdify((x, y), sqrt(x**2 + y**2), 'numpy')
```

The following creates a contour plot, with `c` as the ContourSet object.

```
a = numpy.linspace(-7, 7, 1000)
b = numpy.linspace(-5, 5, 1000)
x, y = numpy.meshgrid(a, b)
c = matplotlib.pyplot.contour(x, y, f(x, y))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm inclined to accept this as a workaround, though the more ideal way out of this is probably for me to file a bug with SymPy to save the ContourSet like how it saves the collections for other kinds of plots.

Comment: @ChristopherChavez yes I agree SymPy should be improved.

Comment: I have [filed an issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12100) with SymPy to see if the ContourSet can be saved. I have rephrased the question to ask specifically for workarounds and have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560424) you learn that you need to keep a reference to your contour plot, from which you can retrieve the points. For your 'Simplest default with labels',   `CS.collections[0].get_paths()`.

But I can't find a way to retrieve the list of plots from a given `axes` object...

In the following code `C` contains the desired collection of lines, but one collection per level in the contour plot and with some scaling:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

X = np.arange(10)
Y = np.arange(10)
Z = np.random.random((10,10))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
A = ax.get_children()
cs = ax.contour (X, Y, Z)
B = ax.get_children()

C = [ref for ref in B if ref not in A]

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
ax2.add_collection(C[0])
```

Which results in `fig`:
[image: fig]
and `fig2`:
[image: fig2]