# Convert plt.contour to np.array (contour graphic value to np.array)

Tags: matplotlib

[image]

Hi, I'm using GeoData and Now I really want to get a contour to array.

I have 3ea array of y,x,z and I draw a contour by `plt.contour(yyy2,xxx2,zzz2,levels=[0.5])`
the contour is drawn by Z=0.5

Now, I want to get this contour line to arrays. (some samples of [yy, xx])

For example....array[[127.7,37.7],[127.6,37.6],[127.5,37.5]....,[127.1,37.1]] is what I wanted.

Any possible method is exist?
Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560424/how-can-i-get-the-x-y-values-of-the-line-that-is-plotted-by-a-contour-plot

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helped! I'm sorry that I did not find a same question by searching... Thank you!!